# como al cargar un combobox desde sqlserver logro que pueda agregar valores null

Tags: .net

Bueno porfavor quisiera que me ayuden en este problema , pondre el codigo:
Este es el procedimiento almacenado

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspListarMarcaXEstado]
@estado int
as
select idmarca,marca,e.manteniento  from Marca m inner join Estado e 
on m.idestado=e.idestado
where e.idestado=@estado
```

Esto esta en la capa Datos

```
 public DataTable ListarproductoxEstado(Producto pro)
        {
            daPro = new SqlDataAdapter("uspListarProductoxEstado", cn.abrirConexion());
            daPro.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            daPro.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", pro.estado.idestado);
            dtPro = new DataTable();
            daPro.Fill(dtPro);
            return dtPro;

        }
```

Bueno en la capa Negocio solo lo llamo al método

Y en la Capa Presentacion

```
  public void cargarMarca()
        {
            Marca mar = new Marca();

            Estado es = new Estado();
            es.idestado = 1;
            mar.estado = es;

            cbomarca.DataSource = marne.ListadoMarcaxEstado(mar);
            cbomarca.DisplayMember = "marca";

            cbomarca.ValueMember = "idmarca";


        }
```

Bueno lo que quiero es lograr es que al momento de insertar un Producto, tenga la opción de que la marca que es un `Combo` pueda quedar vacío es decir `Null`.

```
Marca mar = new Marca();
mar.idmarca = int.Parse(cbomarca.SelectedValue.ToString());
pro.marca = mar;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Yo personalmente no entiendo la pregunta. Considera pulsar en [edit] y ampliarla explicando mejor cual es tu problema.

Comment: ¿Has tratado usando LEFT JOIN en lugar de INNER JOIN?